# UrlEncodedFormEntity giving an error

Tags: android, http-post

I am new to android and I am trying to authenticate my users to google+. It says "The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(ArrayList[]) is undefined" when I am trying to use UrlEncodedFormEntity(). Below is the code, I don't know what I have to do to get rid of that error.

public class Posting extends AsyncTask, Void, Void>{

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... nameValuePair) {


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("accounts.google.com");


     // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your logcat too?

Comment: I can't even run it because there is an error on that line, which is - httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));  it says "The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(ArrayList[]) is undefined" when I hover over the error.